# converting stringbuffer to string and putting words in alphabetized order

Tags: java, stringbuilder

I am trying to read strings from a file and store them in a StringBuffer and then somehow convert that to string and split that string into words and display them in alphabetized order. I can do it without stringbuffer but I have to it. 
this is what I have so far:

```
    public class TextProcessor {
         public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            String input_filename = "input_filename.txt";

             File file1 = new File(input_filename);


             Scanner input = new Scanner(file1);
             StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer("");

             while (input.hasNext()){        
                 String s = input.next();           
                 buffer.append(s);
                             //this is where I need to convert the stringbuffer to
                             // a string and split the words to put them in alphabetized  order
                            // this is what I did 
                 String arr= s.toString().toLowerCase();
                 String [] words = arr.split(" ");// Nothing seems to work.
```

Comment: Why do you "have" to use `StringBuilder`?  It would be simpler to store them in a `List`

Comment: For this assignment I have to use stringbuffer

Comment: Then at least two of the answers should get you moving in the right direction...make sure you know "why" they've being suggested before you blindly implement them ;)

Answer (score 1):

`buffer.toString()` should do it.

But be careful, the `StringBuffer` does NOT add spaces for you. So when you `split(" ")` it won't work.

Fix:

```
buffer.append(s).append(" ");
```

Then:

```
String myString = buffer.toString();
String[] arr = myString.split(" ");
```

But of course, this extra logic could be avoided by taking **MadProgrammer**'s advice, and putting your strings inside a `List` rather than a `StringBuffer`. To order alphabetically, call `Collections.sort(listOfStrings)`.

---

YEY, MORE INFO!

`StringBuffer` is thread-safe, but is less efficient than `StringBuilder`. I suggest you went with `StringBuilder`, given your current knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Two things pop out...

First, you "seem" to be trying to create an array within the loop you are reading the content from.  I assume you want to read the entire file first...

Second, you're not adding in a delimiter into the `StringBuilder`, which means your split will fail as it (likely) does not have anything to split on.

```
while (input.hasNext()){        
    String s = input.next();           
    if (buffer.length() > 0) {
        buffer.append(" ");
    }
    buffer.append(s);
}
String arr= s.toString().toLowerCase();
String [] words = arr.split(" ");// Nothing seems to work.
```

For sorting, you should take a look at [`Arrays.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html).

Personally, I'd use a `List` of some type, but you seem to "have" to use a `StringBuilder`

Answer (score 0):

Complete one is below.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

 public class TextProcessor {

         public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
         {

             String input_filename = "/home/alp/workspace/text.txt";
             String temp_string = null;
             String[] words;
             File file = new File(input_filename);
             Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
             StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

             while (input.hasNext())
             {        
                 String s = input.next();   
                 buffer.append(s).append(" ");
             }
             temp_string= buffer.toString();
             words=temp_string.split(" ");
             Arrays.sort(words);
             for(int i=0; i<words.length; i++) System.out.println(words[i]);
         }
}
```

Comment: How wonderful of you to do the OP's homework for him...but when the teacher asks why they choose to do it this way...will they be able to answer them...?  Also, you could end up with a blank element at the end of the list...

Comment: It seems like he did my homework but the only thing i added to my code is the append(" "). Thank you all for your help.